# Update field in Object array in Meteor (mongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following document:

```
{
   "gameName":"Shooter",
   "details":[
      {
         "submitted":1415215991387,
         "author":"XYZ",
         "subPlayer":{
            "members":{
               "squad1":[
                  {
                     "username":"John",
                     "deaths":0
                  }
               ]
            },
            "gameSlug":"0-shooter"
         }
      }
   ],
   "userId":"foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj",
   "author":"Peter",
   "submitted":1415215991608,
   "lastModified":1415215991608,
   "participants":[
      "CXRR4sGf5AdvSjdgc",
      "foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj"
   ],
   "slug":"1-shooterConv",
   "_id":"p2QQ4TBwidjeZX6YS"
}
```

... and the following Meteor method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateDeaths: function(gameSlug, user, squad) {
            Stats.update({details.subPlayer.gameSlug: gameSlug}, ...}); // ???
    }
});
```

My goal is to update the field `deaths`. The method has the argument `user` which is the user object (username = `user.username`). Furthermore, the argument `squad` is the squad name as string, e.g. `squad1`.

How can I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
db.collection.update(
  {'userId':'foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj', 'details.subPlayer.gameSlug':'0-shooter'}, 
  {'$set': 
     {'details': [{
          'subPlayer': {
               'members': {
                  'squad1':[{'username':'John','death':1}]
               }
          }
       }]
     }
  }
)
```

### UPD:

Also, maybe a better way is to use find().snapshot().forEach(). But I don't know how Meteor supports it. Example:

```
Stats.find({'userId':'foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj', 'details.subPlayer.gameSlug':'0-shooter' }).map(function (e) {
    e.details.forEach(function (d) {
        var squad = 'squad1';
        d.subPlayer.members[squad].forEach(function (s) {
            s.deaths = 10000;
        });
    });
    Stats.update({'_id': e._id}, e);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I think this function is not available in Meteor. `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'findAndModify'`.

Comment: @user3475602 I update my answer. You can use `db.collection.update()` instead of `findAndModify()`

Comment: Thank you! That works. However, now the fields `details.submitted`, `details.author` and `details.subPlayer.gameSlug` will be removed after performing this update. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Furthermore, how can I set the `squad` field dynamically with a String variable? For instance `var squad = 'squad1';`.

Comment: @user3475602 See **upd** section.